# Android Interface Implementation Error for Network Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, networking

I wanted to make a network fragment on my Android app so I could upload and download information from my database server. Following the guide on [Android networking](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html) on the Developer page and the corresponding [example project](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-NetworkConnect) on Github, I created a demo to test a network connection.

I copied the files `DowloadCallback.java` (contains the implemented network interface) and `NetworkFragment.java` (the network fragment thread) word for word from the example project and added the necessary permissions in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

When I tried to implement the fragment into my activity, I got errors in several rather odd and counterintuitive places:

**Code**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements DownloadCallback {
   ...

   @Override
   public void updateFromDownload(String result) {
     ...
   }
}
```

**Errors**

*Class 'MainActivity' must either be declared in abstract or implement method 'updateFromDownload(T)' in 'DownloadCallback'*

*Method does not override method from its superclass*

The public class says it needs a particular method for the class to implement `DownloadCallback`, but when I add such method it says that it does not exist in its superclass. How can these errors coexist? How can I fix this?

By the way, this is the exact same way the main activity class is defined in the sample project. Also I have posted this as an issue on Github but I am hoping to get a quicker response and attention here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

base on [this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html) You have to define `<T>` for `DownloadCallback`
In your case `T` is `String`
So change your code like below

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements DownloadCallback<String>
```

Comment: Wow, now it seems obvious. I am very curious as how this could have slipped by in both the Android developer documentation and the Google Samples repositories I referenced.